# UIImageView animation doesnt work when called from another class

Tags: ios, class, uiview, import, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` with animations, I have a function that starts or stops the animation. From another `UIView` class I call that function, the function gets called and the `if statements` work, but not the startAnimation.

This is the function that start or stop the animation:

```
-(void)runPlayerAnimation:(BOOL)run {
    if (run) [player startAnimating];
    else [player stopAnimating];
}
```

This is the function that calls the function from the `UIView` class:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
if ([self pointInCircle:point]) {
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    GameplayVC *a = [[GameplayVC alloc] init];
    [a runPlayerAnimation:YES];
}
}
```

Both classes import each other like this. In the header file a `@class` is used and in the implementation file `#import` is used.

I have `NSLogged` the living s*** out of the function and everything is working except the `startAnimating` and probably `stopAnimating` too.

Comment: Did you try using `NSNotificationCenter` for this?

Comment: Are you using `setAnimationImages` to initialize the `UIImageView`? If so, are you sure that all of the images in the `NSArray` are initialized properly? It would be easier if posted the code where you initialize your `UIImageView`.

Comment: user2277872: the if statement is working like i said in the question.
Achmed Z: no I havent tried that but i have tried calling the function on mainthreah.
Quentin: Yes im using that, I have tested calling the runPlayerAnimation: function from its class and it works, its when im calling it from the other UIView class it wont work.